# Make AWS CodeBuild artifacts public

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild, artifacts

I have an issue where every time I want to use AWS CodeDeploy, I have to go to S3 and manually make the revision file public since CodeBuild creates an artifact that isn't public.

Is there a way to make CodeBuild create a public artifact in S3? Or is there a way to deploy a non-public artifact using CodeDeploy?

I tried to run some aws s3api commands in post_build phase but they seemed to fail with exit code 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Code Deploy Application will have one more Deployment Group. Each Deployment Group can be assigned with as service IAM Role.

[image]

For this service role we can grant permission to read the S3 bucket so that we dont have to make the artifact every time it is built.

Sample read permission will look like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::woohoo-auto-code-deploy/prod-QC-darpan-be/BuildArtif/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::woohoo-auto-code-deploy/prod-QC-darpan-ui/BuildArtif/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean CodeDeploy?

Comment: Yes.. Edited answer.

Comment: hmm added an inline policy to read all files in my bucket but it still doesn't deploy the new code (same as previous). When I make the artifact public on s3, it deploys the new code. Wondering if there is anything else apart from this policy that needs to be enabled

Comment: can it be that # wget can't be used on private artifacts?

Comment: Had to add both: a policy for the iam role and a policy for the bucket

Comment: Yo don't need a buckt policy, if you are using AWS codedeploy. If you are using wget to get the artifact, well, you may need a bucket policy.

Comment: Umm I am using wget inside of the sh script. Would CodeDeploy pull the artifact even without me adding wget in the script?

Comment: You don't to use wget to get the artifact. Out put of CodeBuild is accessible to the Code Deploy step provided enough permissions are give to access it.

Comment: Hmm if I only put sh scripts to stop and start the app and don't put any sh script that includes wget + link to the revision, it only stops and starts the app but doesn't deploy the new code. How can I deploy the code without any wget ?

Comment: maybe it's the fact I have java -jar jarfile.jar as my app start script. Maybe it is reading the wrong .jar file

Comment: Had to change directory from which I run java -jar to use the new code rather than old one. SOLVED.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your bucket policy for S3 bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1sdhgshjg",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1asdasdadasd",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]
This will make all the objects in your bucket public.

For more info you can read the other examples for [bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

**Note: I assume you have block public access off in your bucket**
[image]

Comment: Had to add both: a policy for the iam role and a policy for the bucket